# Accepting request from specific ip in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, jboss

I referred this tutorial to restrict certain ip in jboss and Spring Boot application.
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-restrict-access-to-jboss-web-application-by-ip-or-host

But the tutorial is not complete. Where should I place those codes? Are there any other methods to do that?

If any one know any other methods please mention that here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the Valves mentioned in tutorial are the ways to customize tomcat embedded into the Jboss application. Note that this tutorial is really old - from 2014, probably JBoss has changed since then.

I remember back that times JBoss indeed included Tomcat inside to handle the web requests, so probably there was some kind of `server.xml` of tomcat.

Now, there are other ways:

1. Place the application behind some proxy that would restrict the access. Probably its the best approach if your environment supports that.
2. Use filters inside the application. You can create a web filter and register it in spring boot application regardless whether its a Jar with embedded server or WAR that you're planning to deploy on JBoss. This can be really flexible but on the other hand it includes some java coding and will consume some resources of your application. You can use this approach if you don't have spring security in your application and you don't want to introduce one, otherwise read (3).
3. Kind of paraphrase on 2 but used with spring security, that has the filtering facility built in: [here is how you can do that](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-whitelist-ip-range). Note that besides the actual Java code used for implementation, 3 and 2 are pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this problem in the following way:

1. If the IP where connections are accepted is subject to change, I'd configure reverse proxy like nginx. This would mean you don't have to redeploy or restart your application if the IP address changes. Please see this guide for details on how to configure `nginx`: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/
2. Otherwise I'd refer to this article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18412 describing the following configuration in `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`:

```
   <valve>
      <class-name>org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve</class-name>
      <param>
          <param-name>allow</param-name>
          <param-value>127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2</param-value>
      </param>
   </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this concern should be handled on infrastructure level, not in application container. I would suggest to look into AWS Security Groups or equivalent concepts in other cloud providers.

If you are running it in private cloud/bare metal, you should investigate to restrict it on transport layer your infrastructure provides. There should be some possibility to configure firewall rules.